# MYSQL Date calculations in 2018

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

I have a mysql script that I have been running every monday for about 8 months through 2017. It has stopped working now we are in 2018.

Here is the code I am having problems with

```
select date_format(date_add(STR_TO_DATE(concat(201750, ' Monday'), '%X%V %W'), interval -7 day),"%x%v")
```

The result as you would expect produces 201749, which is 201750 - 7 days

However the following code

```
    select date_format(date_add(STR_TO_DATE(concat(201802, ' Monday'), '%X%V %W'), interval -7 day),"%x%v")
```

Produces 201802 but it should produce 201801.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this issue. I had to change the format codes from %X%V to %x%v (i.e. from upper case to lower case). Upper case X & V represent a week starting on a Monday and lower case represent Sunday. For some reason the Upper Case works for 2017 but not 2018, however the lower case works for all years that I have tested so far.